# Name in place of number in d3.js pie chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to add text in place of number. Can anybody tell me what I need to do?

this is the code----

http://jsbin.com/zocewinoye/2/edit?html,output

Please check it and help me....

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please see the [ask] page and revise your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your labels:

```
// Labels
arcs.append("text")
    ...
    .text(function(d) {
        return 'hello';
    });
```

If your data array was an array of strings:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then to display them you could:

```
    ...
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

If your data array was an array of objects:

```
[{val: 1, label: 'a'}, {val: 2, label: 'b'}, {val: 3, label: 'c'}]
```

Then to display labels you could:

```
    ...
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

Comment: If I have text in array

like var x= [abs,jln];

Then how can I use it?

Comment: You can access them from `d` argument. It represents iterated values from your data array.

Comment: I wrote 
var k=["f","v","b","d"];

.....

.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text(function(k) {
        return k.value;
       });

its not working @Oleg

Comment: You have two different `k` in there. They are not the same. And even if they were, `k.value` doesn't make sense because you don't have any `value` properties.

Comment: So how should i use it.

Comment: its works with small error. It shows all arrays values at a same time aty very arc..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/guxetadenu/2/edit

Comment: Thanks, @Oleg you help me alot. I have an another problem which I asked to many person but no one could answer. Like the pie chart you gave me, I want to save that chart in seperate .js file and want to link it to my html and can add dataset value manually. can you tell me how can i do this?

Comment: @rohitnarang It's best to make an attempt or do a little research before asking. Otherwise, people might think you're a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: @showdev sorry if i did anything wrong.